# how to create complex grid in bootstrap 3, (column rowspan)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table

how to create following grid with bootstrap 3 ?
i checked out many answers but didn't find a solution to my grid.

- [Bootstrap combining rows (rowspan)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351404/bootstrap-combining-rows-rowspan)
- [Twitter Bootstrap 3 rowspan and reorder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21241862/twitter-bootstrap-3-rowspan-and-reorder)
- [Create a rowspan in bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16520717/create-a-rowspan-in-bootstrap)

[image: bootstrap 3 grid with row-span]

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap 3, the `.span*` classes have been removed, and replaced with a combination of `.col-*` classes: `.col-xs-*`, `.col-sm-*`, `.col-md-*`, and `.col-lg-*`.

[Source](http://blog.jetstrap.com/2013/08/bootstrap-3-grids-explained/)

Answer (score 0):

Make 3 big columns and inside each just add more rows as you need them.

Example:

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4">
     <p>left column text here you can also add another row here with more cols inside</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Here is the refrence on the grid system: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid